# ProxyError Raised with Requests module

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am still new to python and can't figure out how to handle this error and what to do with it to avoid it even after trying to understand the different methods of the Requests module and reading out there.

Here's the simple request I use where *line* loops through a text file with the different URL I'm trying to access and *d* a list of dictionary containing the many URLs I'm using as proxies.

```
import requests
import collections

# [...]
d = collections.deque(proxies)

with requests.session() as r:
    d.rotate(-1)
    page = r.get(line.rstrip(), proxies=d[0])
```

It works perfectly until one of the proxies from the list timeout for some reason and force the script to raise this error:

```
ProxyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\Christopher Fargere\desktop\python\quick_scraper.py in <module>()
     72         with requests.session() as r:
     73                 d.rotate(-1)
---> 74                 page = r.get(line.rstrip(), proxies=d[0])
     75                 print d[0]
     76                 print page.status_code
 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    393
    394         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 395         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    396
    397     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert)
    381             'allow_redirects': allow_redirects,
    382         }
--> 383         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    384
    385         return resp

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    484         start = datetime.utcnow()
    485         # Send the request
--> 486         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    487         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    488         r.elapsed = datetime.utcnow() - start

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    379
    380         except _ProxyError as e:
--> 381             raise ProxyError(e)
    382
    383         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:

ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
```

I would love to implement an IF condition when an error is raised that pops out the proxy out of the *d* list and retry the same URL. I'm sure its very simple but can't understand how the errors are raised in Python. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To catch an exception, use [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html); catch the `ProxyError` thrown:

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError

with requests.session() as r:
    page = None

    for _ in range(len(d)):
        d.rotate(-1)
        try:
            page = r.get(line.rstrip(), proxies=d[0])
        except ProxyError:
            # ignore proxy exception, move to next proxy
            pass
        else:
            # success, break loop
            break

    if page is None:
        # none of the proxies worked
        raise ProxyError
```

This tries, at most, all your proxies in `d`, one by one. If none of them worked, we raise the `ProxyError` again, as you probably want to know that all your proxies failed at that time.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I thought the 'case' control flow didn't exist in python. That'd indeed very handy. :D
Now, I've got more one question though cause I've got issues getting other commands being executed once I break the loop : If I 'break' instructions within the block 'with requests.session() as r:' it won't allow me to process any more commands in there, right?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit fast in posting my comment. If you could just enlighten me on my edited comment above, that'd be fantastic. :)

Comment: @fassn: I structured a loop based on what you gave in your post; you'd put more code that needs the `r` session to be active after the `if page is None` section, or put more code using the current proxy within the `try:`/`except` perhaps.

Comment: @fassn: but the `break` is meant to end the `for _ in range(len(d))` loop, because we no longer need to loop to the next proxy.

Comment: thanks perfect! I think I figured out my logic mistake that gave me the feeling the *break* instruction was also stopping the rest of the parent loop!

Comment: why is deque being used here ... it seems like it would be easier to just `for proxy in a_list`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I didn't pay attention to the deque; yes a simple `for` loop would do just fine here.